# How to get this table to display?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to get this table to work (code shown at bottom)

[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogqxgv?editors=110) *(please try deleting "**display:inline-block**" from ".article2" in CSS to see the difference.)*

I need the articles to be scrollable (overflow:auto), and the titles to line up properly.

But when I add in the "display:inline-block", the titles' layout will be messed up. But if I remove it, the scrolling will be disabled.

Can't figure out how to get the titles in the right places.

```
<table id="wrapper2">
    <tr>
          <td class="articletitle">
            <h3>Title of 1st article</h3>
          </td>

          <td class="articletitle">
            <h3>Title of 2nd article</h3>
          </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
          <td class="article2">
            <p>Herp derpsum derps sherper herpy mer nerpy terp. Nerpy ter derpus derps. Herpem derps herpler herderder. Serp perp ner berp herpy perper dee derpsum tee derpus. Merp perp sherper derpler nerpy sherlamer derpy herpderpsmer dee. Sherp herpderpsmer merp derpus sherpus terp der serp. Terp derpus, sherlamer herpem serp. Sherlamer herp herpy herpderpsmer merp ner sherp der. Dee sherlamer sherp mer. Der herpy herp ler sherper. Berps derperker dee sherpus derpus ter perper, sherper herpler serp.<br><br><br><br><br></p>     
          </td>

          <td class="article2">
            <p>Serp derpler ter herp berp derpy herpler. Derperker derps merp ner perper herderder derpler herp derp. Derperker sherpus derps der berp derpy. Terp derp der mer. Ler terp merp derpsum derp tee. Serp derpus sherp derpler. Perp ner dee derpy sherpus derpler tee. Herpy herpem herp, der herderder serp perp derp ler. Dee ler herpderpsmer nerpy. Terp derp derpsum mer. Sherper tee ter, derps sherlamer. Derpus berps ner herpy mer dee sherlamer sherp. Serp herpem herpy derpler derps herpsum tee merpus.<br><br><br><br><br></p>
          </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

#wrapper2 {
max-width: 90%;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.articletitle {
    text-indent: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(50,50,50);
}

.article2 {
      display:inline-block;
    max-width: 40%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    font-family: "minerva-modern",sans-serif;
    text-indent: 50px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    overflow: auto;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    content: "";
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000 120px, #fff);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `overflow: auto` shouldn't be applied to the `td` itself. Put the article body into another container (i.e. `div`, `article` or something else) and apply the `overflow: auto` to it.

I've made a [fiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kLmzzjh1/) with (almost) your own CSS but modifying the HTML source.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: WOW Thanks a lot! 
I can't upvote due to lack of reputations :(

Comment: Yes, it does indeed. Thank you!